# ggplot2 & facet_wrap - eliminate vertical distance between facets

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm working with some data that I want to display as a nxn grid of plots. **Edit:** To be more clear, there's 21 categories in my data. I want to facet by category, and have those 21 plots in a 5 x 5 square grid (where the orphan is by itself on the fifth row). Thus facet_wrap instead of facet_grid.

I've got the following code written up for doing it (using the good old iris data set for my reproducible example):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

cust_theme <- theme_bw() + theme(legend.position="none", 
              axis.title = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
              axis.text = element_blank(), strip.text = element_blank(), 
              strip.background = element_blank(), panel.margin = unit(0, "lines"), 
              panel.border = element_rect(size = 0.25, color = "black"), 
              panel.grid = element_blank())

iris.plot <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
             geom_point() + cust_theme + facet_wrap( ~ Species, ncol = 2) + 
             labs(title = "Irises by species")
```

This gives me ALMOST what I want, but not quite:

[image: Plot of iris data set per above code.]

I've still got a tiny strip of space between the top row of plots and the bottom row. I'd like to get rid of that entirely, but panel.margin is obviously not doing it. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You may want to place your `+` operators on the end of the line as the code as is will produce an error in an R script. Alternatively, you can wrap the whole plot call in parentheses.

Comment: @cr1msonB1ade Thanks, good point. It's all one line in my code but I broke it up for readability. Fixed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the `panel.margin` argument to `panel.margin = unit(c(-0.5,0-0.5,0), "lines")`. For some reason the top and bottom margins need to be negative to line up perfectly. Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Oh huzzah! I suspect you need to force them to be negative because that space is reserved for the x axis even when it's not drawn.

Comment: Nice hack. @plagueheart the space is actually reserved for the facet-strip.

Comment: Okay, this is frustrating--for some reason it's working properly with my dummy plot, but when I apply it to the original case I was working with, the gaps are still there.

Comment: Fixed it by switching to panel.margin.y = unit(c(-0.5,-0.5), "lines"), panel.margin.x = unit(0,"lines"). I have no idea what's going wrong with just panel.margin, but this works even if it's a little hacky.

Answer (score 10):

This might be a little late, but `panel.margin`is now deprecated. Inside `theme` use `panel.spacing`. To eliminate the spacing between the facets then load the `grid` package and use `panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines")`

Comment: panel.spacing manages the gaps between panels. But how do we manage the gaps between the line chart and the border? Like is there a similar way to pad pixels between the extreme ends of the y-axis and x-axis?

Comment: Do you mean `plot.margin`? If you're looking to just expand the size of the chart (closer to the margin) you can use something like `theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5,0.2,0.5,1), "cm"))`. Just have to find the size that works best for you.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep this in mind when I get to my old plots where the label text (over the line) was getting cut at the border.

Answer (score 5):

You can also edit the grobs directly:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

g <-  ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap( ~ Species, ncol = 2) +
  labs(title = "Irises by species") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.margin = unit(0, "lines")) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0,0,0,0), "lines")) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(plot.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(strip.text = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks.margin = unit(0, "lines"))

g <- ggplotGrob(p)

g$heights[[7]] = unit(0, "lines")

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you. I'm a little shy of working with grobs still but I'll get there eventually--will keep this in mind as another solution.